# What does "pypi" in the "Channel" column of `conda list` output imply?

Tags: conda, pypi

```
$ conda list -v torch-glow
# packages in environment at /anaconda3/envs/pytorch:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
torch-glow                0.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Does it mean that I `pip install`'d the `torch-glow` package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means you used `pip install` as described in the docs: 
https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages

> The command `conda list` shows packages installed this way, with a label showing that they were installed with pip.

Please note that:

> Issues may arise when using pip and conda together. When combining conda and pip, it is best to use an isolated conda environment. Only after conda has been used to install as many packages as possible should pip be used to install any remaining software. If modifications are needed to the environment, it is best to create a new environment rather than running conda after pip. When appropriate, conda and pip requirements should be stored in text files.

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env